# Meteor.js: How to avoid useless refresh/computation/re-render with dot notation

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm needing a way to avoid useless computations;
In reactive functions, I have a reactive object, I just need one property, but if one other of this object change, all the function is recalculated:

```
Template.registerHelper('name', function() {
    console.log("running");
    return Meteor.user().profile.name;
});
```

(In html

```
<body><p>My name: {{name}}</p></body>
```

)

Now let change your age:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()},{$set:{"profile.age":20}});
```

You guess what you see in your console(for the second time...)

```
running               x2
```

but it should run only once because the name haven't changed

Why it's important ? In my application I have complex calculs, and user online/idle status is changing easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation is rerun whenever the value of used reactive function changes. In your case, the reactive function is `Meteor.user()`, so whenever result of that method changes, rerun is triggered.

To limit reruns to where it's really necessary, you need to use (or create) a reactive function that will return exactly the value you want to track and nothing more. For example:

```
var prop = new ReactiveVar();

Template.template.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    prop.set(Meteor.user().profile.name);
  });
});

Template.template.helpers({
  hlpr: function() {
    console.log("RERUN!!!");
    return prop.get();
  },
});
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to always do it ? Because I have created a fonctions to do it easily, and I will publish it in a package

Comment: To self answer, thanks so much ! I have also learn myself that using array of reactive object in template is realy a bad idea